# If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product $K \times (G / K)$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of the group $G$. Is it true that the direct product of $K$ by $G/K$ is isomorphic to $G$? Which isomorphism can we define from $K\times G/K$ to $G$?

Comment: Is it true for $G=Z_4$ and $K=Z_2$? ($Z_n$ = cyclic group with $n$ elements)

Comment: $2ℤ × ℤ/2ℤ ≠ ℤ$.

Answer (score 2):

In general this is false. A minimal example is $G := \Bbb Z_4$, $K := \Bbb Z_2$. Then, $G / K \cong \Bbb Z_2$, but then $G$ has elements of order $4$ whereas $K \times (G / K)$ does not, so $$G \not\cong K \times (G / K).$$

Another easy example is $G := S_3$, $K := A_3 \cong \Bbb Z_3$, for which $G$ is nonabelian but $K \times (G / K)$ is not.

Comment: I ask this because in the book "An Introduction to the theory of groups" third edition of Joseph J. Rotman in page 128 is written: "If $G$ is a group having a normal subgroup $K$, then we can "factor"  $G$ into the two groups $G/K$ and $K$". what does that mean?

Comment: If we choose representatives $g_K\in G$ for each coset $g_KK\in G/K$ then $G$ is the disjoint union of the $g_KK$ and any element $g\in G$ is of the form $g_Kk$ for some $g_K$ and $k\in K$. This doesn't necessarily give the isomorphism, but still feels like factoring $G$

Comment: @user166934 I can't improve on TheRob's excellent comment, but let me point out that one can combine two groups ways other than direct products. The most important of these (which actually generalizes the direct product) is the *semidirect product* $N \rtimes K$, where $N$ is normal, and many important groups can be "factored" into such a product.